# why we don't use CMD apt update instead of RUN apt update on Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

why we don't use CMD apt update instead of RUN apt update on **Dockerfile**

we use **RUN apt update** for update an image this is for one time but why we don't use **CMD apt update** for update every container we create ? ? ? ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it sounds like you already know, `RUN` is intended "xecute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results", and `CMD` is intended to "xecute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results". So `RUN` is a build-time instruction, while `CMD` is a run-time instruction.

There are a few reasons this won't be a good idea:

1. Containers should be fast

Containers are usually expected to consume as few resources as possible, and startup and shutdown quickly and easily. If we update a container's packages **EVERY** time we want to run a container, it might take the container many minutes or even hours on a bad network before it can even start running whatever process it is intended for.

2. Unexpected behavior

Part of the process when developing a new container image is ensuring that the packages that are necessary for the container to work, play well together. But if we are upgrading all the packages each time the container is run on whatever system it is run on, it is possible (if not inevitable) that there will eventually be a package that will be published that introduces a breaking change to the container, and this is obviously not ideal.

Now this *could* be avoided by removing the default repositories and replacing them with your own where you can vet each package upgrade, test them together, and publish them, but this is probably a much greater effort than what would make sense unless the repos would be serving multiple container images.

3. Image Versioning

Many container images (ex [Golang](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang/?tab=description/)) will version their images based on the version of Golang they support; however, when the underlying packages on the container are changing how would you start to version the image?

Now this isn't necessarily a deal breaker, but it could cause confusion among the containers user-base and ultimately undercut their trust in the container.

3. Unexpected network traffic

Even if well documented, most developers would not expect this type of functionality and would lead to development issues when your container requires access to the internet. For example, in a K8s environment networking can be extremely strict and the developer would need to manually open up a route to the internet (or a set of custom repos).

Additionally, even if the networking is not an issue, if you expected a lot of these containers to be started, you might be clogging the network with the upgrade packages and cause network performance issues.

4. Wouldn't work for base images

While it sounds like you are probably not developing an image intended to serve as a base image for anything else... but obviously the `CMD` likely would be overriden for the base image.

Comment: To add another to the list, it requires you run the containers as root.

Comment: There's definitely a lot that I've missed, I'll wait for a bit and add any new ones (with credit) as a big edit.

Comment: So, Do we must write `RUN apt update or upgrade` when building image in Dockerfile.

Comment: The various base images like `ubuntu:20.04` do update themselves fairly routinely, so as long as you regularly pull your base image, don't pin to a super-specific patch level of a language runtime image, and don't need any additional OS-level packages, I'd argue you don't need to `RUN apt-get upgrade` normally.

Comment: But I saw a lot of images wrote `RUN apt-get upgrade`

Comment: @AhmedApdulRasool its mostly a convention that a lot of people use to ensure that their system is as up to date as possible. DavidMaze is right that its *probably* not necessary if you are using the most up to date version of the container, but a lot of folks still do it either without thinking, or just out of an abundance of caution.